# aws glue job to import dynamodb data

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

We are trying to do DynamoDB migration from prod account to stage account.

In the source account, we are making use of "Export" feature of DDB to put the compressed .json.gz files into destination S3 bucket.

We have written a glue script which will read the exported .json.gz files and writes it to DDB table.

We are making the code generic, so we should be able to migrate any DDB table from prod to stage account.

As part of that process, while testing we are facing issues when we are trying to write a NUMBER SET data to target DDB table.

Following is the sample snippet which is raising ValidationException when trying to insert into DDB

```
from decimal import Decimal

def number_set(datavalue):
    # datavalue will be ['0', '1']
    set_of_values = set()
    for value in datavalue:
        set_of_values.add(Decimal(value))
    return set_of_values
```

When running the code, we are getting following `ValidationException`
`An error occurred while calling o82.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: UKEU70T0BLIKN0K2OL4RU56TGVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)`

However, if instead of `Decimal(value)` if we use `int(value)` then no `ValidationException` is being thrown and the job succeeds.

I feel that `write_dynamic_frame_from_options` will try to infer schema based on the values the element contains, if the element has "int" values then the datatype would be "NS", but if the element contains all "Decimal type" values, then it is not able to infer the datatype.

The glue job we have written is

```
dyf = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options={
        "paths": [file_path]
    },
    format="json",
    transformation_ctx = "dyf",
    recurse = True,
)

def number_set(datavalue):
    list_of_values = []
    for value in datavalue:
        list_of_values.append(Decimal(value))
    print("list of values ")
    print(list_of_values)
    return set(list_of_values)

def parse_list(datavalue):
    list_of_values = []
    for object in datavalue:
        list_of_values.append(generic_conversion(object))
    return list_of_values
        
def generic_conversion(value_dict):
    for datatype,datavalue in value_dict.items():
        if datatype == 'N':
            value = Decimal(datavalue)
        elif datatype == 'S':
            value = datavalue
        elif datatype == 'NS':
            value = number_set(datavalue)
        elif datatype == 'BOOL':
            value = datavalue
        elif datatype == 'M':
            value = construct_map(datavalue)
        elif datatype == 'B':
            value = datavalue.encode('ascii')
        elif datatype == 'L':
            value = parse_list(datavalue)
    return value
        

def construct_map(row_dict):
    ddb_row = {}
    for key,value_dict in row_dict.items():
        # value is a dict with key as N or S
        # if N then use Decimal type
        ddb_row[key] = generic_conversion(value_dict)
    return ddb_row

def map_function(rec):
    row_dict = rec["Item"]
    return construct_map(row_dict)


mapped_dyF = Map.apply(frame = dyf, f = map_function, transformation_ctx = "mapped_dyF")
datasink2 = glue_context.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    frame=mapped_dyF,
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.region": "us-east-1",
        "dynamodb.output.tableName": destination_table,
        "dynamodb.throughput.write.percent": "0.5"
    },
    transformation_ctx = "datasink2"
)
```

can anyone help us in how can we unblock from this situation?

Record that we are trying to insert

```
{
  "region": {
    "S": "to_delete"
  },
  "date": {
    "N": "20210916"
  },
  "number_set": {
    "NS": [
      "0",
      "1"
    ]
  },
  "test": {
    "BOOL": false
  },
  "map": {
    "M": {
      "test": {
        "S": "value"
      },
      "test2": {
        "S": "value"
      },
      "nestedmap": {
        "M": {
          "key": {
            "S": "value"
          },
          "nestedmap1": {
            "M": {
              "key1": {
                "N": "0"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "binary": {
    "B": "QUFBY2Q="
  },
  "list": {
    "L": [
      {
        "S": "abc"
      },
      {
        "S": "def"
      },
      {
        "N": "123"
      },
      {
        "M": {
          "key2": {
            "S": "value2"
          },
          "nestedmaplist": {
            "M": {
              "key3": {
                "S": "value3"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: In the boto3 documentation, these are the allowed mappings between DynamoDB types and python 
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/types.html

Comment: Heard back from AWS support team, there is a bug in DynamicFrame writer class. When it tries to write set([decimal.Decimal]), DynamicFrame seems to lose the data and tries to write {"number_set":<empty>}, to the DynamoDB. 
When we try to insert a key/value pair into DynamoDB without a proper value, we get the Supplied AttributeValue is empty exception

Comment: I ran your code @madhu and I found that you could change your `Decimal(Datavalue)` code to `float(Datavalue)` and it wrote the record fine.

I also had to switch for the `NULL | null` data type if you switch.

Comment: hi @ted-k42, if we use `float(Datavalue)` then we may loose precision. We have a usecase where we dont want to loose precision, hence we need to use `Decimal(Datavalue)`.

Comment: @madhusudhan have you dealt with SS (string set) dynamodb datatypes and if so how have you handled those?  Similar to NS?  Thank you for sharing your code.  This is very helpful.  I kind of wish that the unnestddbjson would just do all the datatype inference and we wouldn't have to do this level of datatype mapping.  But unnest option just converts everything to strings.

Comment: @db_brad i dont think i dealt with SS datatypes. I do feel the same regarding datatype inference, or may be a schema to define datatypes would be helpful.

Comment: @madhusudhan I spoke with our AWS rep to see if we could get an enhancement request in for unnestddbjson to infer the schema and not just convert all columns to strings.  Stay tuned.